# Calculate limit of the sum

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

What's the following limit?

$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{{n\choose k}}{k!!})$

where ${n\choose k}$ is the binomial coefficient and k!! = $k \cdot (k-2) \cdot (k-4) \cdot...$.

What about:

$\lim_{{n \to \infty}} \left( \frac{\sum_{{k=0}}^{n} \frac{{n \choose k}}{{k!!}}}{2^{2n}} \right)
$?

Comment: Do you mean how to do this in the computing software *Mathematica* (which this site is about), or did you perhaps intend to post this on [math.se]?

Comment: There is strong [graphical evidence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pbshr.png) that the sum diverges to infinity. I am not a mathematician, but maybe it could be helpful to rewrite the binomial on top in terms of factorials ($\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$) and show that this grows faster than double factorial

Comment: I changed your LaTeX for the last line so it would show. I am not sure if that is exactly what you wanted. Feel free to correct it if it isn't.

Comment: *limes* Do you mean “limit”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `k!!==Factorial2[k]`

```
f[n_]=Sum[Binomial[n, k]/k!!, {k, 0, n}]
```

```
(Gamma[1 + n] HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2 - n/2, 1 - n/2}, {3/2, 3/2}, 1/
   2])/Gamma[n] + 
 HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2 - n/2, -(n/2)}, {1/2, 1}, 1/2]
```

- The graphics indicate that `f[n]->∞` and `f[n]/2^(2 n)->0` as `n->∞`.

```
{DiscretePlot[f[n], {n, 1, 100}], 
 DiscretePlot[f[n]/2^(2 n), {n, 1, 100}]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

define `k!!`

```
fac2[k_] := Which[EvenQ[k], 2^(k/2) (k/2)!, True, (k + 1)!/(2^((k + 1)/2)((k + 1)/2)!)]

sum[n_] := Sum[Binomial[ n, k]/fac2[k], {k, 0, n, 2} ]
```

Sum probably diverges

```
Table[{n, sum[n]}, {n, {10, 100, 1000}}] // N
(*{{10., 54.2424}, {100., 6.8435*10^11}, {1000., 2.67141*10^61}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

First define the sum as a function of n:

```
f[n_]= Sum[Binomial[n, k]/k!, {k, 0, n}]

Hypergeometric1F1[-n, 1, -1]
```

Then calculate the limit n->Infinity:

```
Limit[f[n], n -> Infinity]

∞
```

Comment: it is `k!!` not `k!`